# Select only parent

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to toggle a parent div when the div itself is being clicked. But I want to prevent child divs or elements from triggering the function. How can I do that?

```
//javascript (jquery enabled)
function toggle(parent_id) {
  $('.'+parent_id).toggle();
}
<!-- html -->
<div class="parent parent1" onclick="toggle('parent1')">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
</div>

<div class="parent parent2" onclick="toggle('parent2')">
  <div class="child1"></div>
  <div class="child2"></div>
</div>
```

Thanks!

UPDATE: I'm trying to toggle the specific div, hence using a function to pass the specific parent id.

ie. if I click on parent1, parent1 toggles; 
if I click on parent2, parent2 toggles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following should do the job:

```
$(".parent").click(function(e) {
    if (e.target == this) {
        $(this).toggle();
    }
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/Md4U5/

Comment: Yes, embrace the power of "THIS".

Comment: One addition @VisioN, I always like to test for target with: `var eTarget = e.target !== null ? e.target : e.srcElement;` otherwise +1 for ya haha

Comment: @mcpDESIGNS Nice catch, thanks! However, it may confuse the OP ;)

Answer (score 0):

That's easy, just extend @VisioN's answer, ensuring that all those `div`s have a class of `parent`:

```
$("[class~=parent]").click(function(e) {
    if (e.target == this) {
        $(this).toggle();
    }
});
```